# Append data in select (option) got from server

Tags: javascript, php, html, django, ajax

I am trying to append the data got from Server via AJAX task in the select options but whenever the append function get executed by clicking the select Button(Day) each time the data get appended like this:
1, 2 ,3.... 1, 2, 3
Means the same data gets appended multiple times (i.e. each time when button is clicked).

```
   <div class="form-group col-sm-3 d-inline-block" style="padding: 0px;">
    <select class="form-control" id="Day" name='day' onclick="get_max_np_date()">
        <option disabled selected>Day</option>
        <script>
            var max_day;
            function get_max_np_date() { //Return the maximum Days in Nepali Date System (Bikram Sambat)
                var get_year = document.getElementById('Year') 
                var get_month = document.getElementById('Month'); 
                
                year = get_year.options[get_year.selectedIndex].value;
                month = get_month.options[get_month.selectedIndex].value;
                console.log(Boolean(year && month));
                if (year && month){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'max-np-day',
                        type: 'get',
                        data: {
        
                        'year':year,
                        'month':month
        
                        },
        
        
                        success: function (data) {
                            max_day = data;
                            var days;
                            DayElm = document.getElementById("Day")

                            for (days = 1; days <= max_day; days++) {
                                var optionElm = document.createElement("option");
                                var daysNode = document.createTextNode(days);
                                optionElm.appendChild(daysNode)
                                DayElm.appendChild(optionElm)
                            }
                              
                        }
                        
                        })
                }
        
            };
            </script>
        </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you empty your select-box before appending new data ? i.e : `document.getElementById("Day").innerHTML = "";`

Comment: `<select class="form-control" id="Day" name='day' onclick="get_max_np_date()">` Where should I need to put it because when added `.innerHTML = "";` it clear the data inside select and whenever I click any option I didn't show me the choosed option

Comment: Inside your `success function` and before appending new data i.e : before `for-loop`.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't worked. As I click in any `option` the clicked option didn't chosen.

Comment: what do you mean by `clicked option didn't chosen..` ? Also, there is no  closing tag for select i.e :`</select>`

Comment: clicked `option` don't get choosed(i.e. selected). Sorry for typos

Comment: Check the comment video HERE: https://www.facebook.com/groups/codingislife/permalink/697674224474991/

Comment: I've added it (`</select>`) lastly but I forgot to update it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222536/discussion-between-swati-and-bishwas-bhandari).

Comment: Check the two images in imgur: https://imgur.com/a/0n5nmEP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood your requirement as you've told me in `FB`. It's simple...

1. Pass id's of `Month` and `Year` in their respective select tag.
2. Ue `on change` function

   $( "#{{Month}}, #{{Year}}" ).on( "change", function()
   {
   ....CODE STUFF
   ....
   })